# First time askers modal

Tags: discussion, feature-request, asking-questions

#### Stipulations

The first time askers modal has [two required parts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/377059): A sentence about searching for existing answers on the site, and a list of specific actions. These have to stay in place. However, we can propose changing the text before the search sentence, and text between the search sentence and the list. We can also request to drop the third item in the list. Here is a visual from the linked [meta.stackexchange post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/377059):

[image]

#### The process

We discussed possible guidance to first askers in this [meta post](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5216/how-can-we-guide-new-users-before-they-ask-their-first-question), and had specific proposals in this [meta post](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5219/72973). We are now putting forward the top proposal, modified to fit the exact stipulations.

#### The proposal

Based on this, we now propose the following modal (this proposal has the support of the current moderators). It uses the first two items in the list, and there are two blocks of Chemistry-specific guidance (before and after the sentence about search before you post):

[image]

**For easier copying and pasting, and for checking this on different screen sizes and aspect ratios, here is a text version as well**:

##### Asking a good question

Welcome to Chemistry Stack Exchange! To get you the best answer, we provide this guidance for first-time askers.

Before you post, [search the site](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/72973) to make sure your question hasn’t been answered.

Follow our policies when asking [homework-like](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141) questions (questions about problem sets, exam items, etc.). Carefully write your question, using clear language, technical terms and [formatting](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/notation) as best as you can. Give sufficient [context](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) (what you understand and where you need help). It helps us and helps you.

1. Summarize the problem
2. Provide details and any research

[**Start writing**]

#### Next steps

If you want to express community support for this proposal, you can upvote this question. If you have other feedback, you can use comments or answers.

Comment: Why can't this be applied to all sites! :3

Answer (score 1):

I am curious to know why point #3 ("When appropriate, describe what you've tried") was dropped. Is it unimportant, irrelevant or redundant?

Otherwise the only point I would argue is important (as in "sweeps a problem under the carpet", or "sweeps the elephant in the room under the carpet") is the implicit interpretation of homework ("questions about problem sets, exam items, etc"). The link of course provides a broader definition of what is meant by homework. Maybe sub that sentence with "for instance from problem sets or exams" ?

Otherwise I find nothing to nitpick.

Comment: I deleted the third point because I wanted to keep it as short as possible while saying the site-specific things. I felt that the sentence "Give sufficient context (what you understand and where you need help)" was more helpful than "When appropriate, describe what you tried".