# How to actually ask question

Tags: discussion

I don't know but, it is my observation but this site is very unfriendly to novice people like me. Note that I am a high school student Asking simple questions like [this](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/169296/difficulty-in-heterogenous-equilibria), or [this](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/141159/reactivity-dilemma-of-elements), only results in being downvoted, although I am following all the following rules:

1. asking for a specific concept or to resolve doubt in that concept
2. Writing as clearly, and respectfully as possible
3. Showing my understanding and building question around it.

However following rules won't help me at all. I haven't faced such issues in other sites like physics, and mathematics. I was banned for several months *for asking bad questions*.
So as respectfully as possible I am asking, what can I do to improve the quality of my questions?
Why are they being downvoted? Why novices like me are treated like this? If you take a glance on questions on this site, most novices like us have downvoted questions.

Comment: You can follow the [first time askers modal](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5242/first-time-askers-modal). Community is always there to help you: https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5255/how-do-we-help-new-users-that-have-a-novice-chemistry-background-write-questions/5257 ... https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5205/in-2022-how-can-we-use-comments-to-welcome-new-users-and-encourage-them-to-impr/5214

Comment: For starters, is "Difficulty in heterogenous equilibria" a good title according to you? Any "difficulty", "question", "confusion", etc. is a buzzword that has no place in title. You shouldn't put a buzzword instead of trying to define the issue properly.

Comment: I can totally relate. you see, not surprisingly you got downvoted even for this non-chemistry question as well. Maybe you need to "research" about this as well before asking? (sarcasm intended)

Answer (score 6):

What is missing from the rules you cited is to do some research, and to document that research when you ask.

For example, one of your questions asks about reactivity. This is a tag on this site, and is explained as follows:

> Questions tagged [reactivity]
>
> Applied to a chemical species, the term expresses a kinetic property in reference to another species. The tag should be applied to questions seeking answers with respect to the reactivity (or unreactivity) of a certain chemical compound, species, molecular entity and/or functional groups. It must not be applied to questions about the stability of certain chemical species.

If reactivity describes how fast one species turns into another, and you are asking about elements, you would have to add what these elements would react with, and what the product would be.

For the alkaline metals, the reactivity with water to form oxides and elemental hydrogen might be what you are asking about. For boron and nitrogen, it is hard to guess. Sometimes, the comments can guide you in doing more research and editing the question after you posted it. However, it is best if you can do some research (on the chemistry site and elsewhere) before you post, or when you post (the site often points out questions automatically that might be relevant).

Answer (score 5):

This is a recurrent problem for novices. It often has to do with the novelty of the questions asked. Have you browsed the site to see if there are similar questions to yours, with satisfactory answers? Many users regard questions that have previously been asked as less than useful and downvote. This is not a tutoring site, it is a Q&A site. It aims, on paper at least, to assemble the best possible answers to unique questions, with a minimum of bloat. The questions and answers should be clear and relatively concise. In practice different users may encounter a problem in a unique way and that's often ok, but experienced participants may perceive the description of a problem as flawed, for instance demanding too long or broad an answer, requiring more detail or clarity, or not demonstrating that there really is a problem rather than a trivial confusion.

This is my general interpretation, and not necessarily specific to your case, although some of the above may be true (I do not represent those who voted on your questions). Admittedly you posted fairly tidy and well structured questions. I can understand your frustration and hope this is of some help in [avoiding further bans](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/question-bans).